# Groupby, sum with multiple joins in Linq lambda

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I have the below Linq query, and I want to sum the *Hours* based on the `WorkItem.Id`:

```
EntryCategories
           .Join(TimeReportEntries,
                 ec => ec.Id,
                 tr => tr.WorkItem.Id,
                 (ec, tr) => new { ec, tr })
                            .Join(Timesheets,
                                  ecs => ecs.tr.Timesheet.Id,
                                  t => t.Id,
                                  (ecs, t) => new { ecs, t })
                                              .Join(Users,
                                                    ts => ts.t.User.Id,
                                                    u => u.Id,
                                                    (ts, u) => new
                                                        {
                                                            Employee = ts.t.User.FirstName + " " + ts.t.User.LastName,
                                                            Hours = ts.ecs.tr.Hours
                                                        });
```

Comment: @Yosi - Seems like they want to get the Sum of `Hours` and group by `WorkItem.Id` from the above query, by extending it or having a new object to hold it

Comment: Ok, good luck :), but what is the question?

Comment: @Yosi - How - I assume :), not sure myself, it's too late in the day to try and work out what's actually in that result set. OP, can you show us the current result set from that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea as to how exactly you want it to work and cant compile it here, but I think you need a group by to get sum of hours by each work item, and that is what you're after.

```
EntryCategories
       .Join(TimeReportEntries, ec => ec.Id, tr => tr.WorkItem.Id, (ec, tr) => new { ec, tr })
       .Join(Timesheets, ecs => ecs.tr.Timesheet.Id, t => t.Id, (ecs, t) => new { ecs, t })
       .Join(Users, ts => ts.t.User.Id, u => u.Id, (ts, u) => new
        {
            WorkItemId = ts.ecs.tr.WorkItem.Id
            Employee = ts.t.User.FirstName + " " + ts.t.User.LastName,
            Hours = ts.ecs.tr.Hours
        })
       .GroupBy(x => x.WorkItemId)
       .Select(x => new 
        { 
            WorkItemId = x.Key, 
            Hours = x.Sum(y => y.Hours)
        });
```